# SublimeText3 + EventListener - How to bind class method to on_query_completions method

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am creating plugin of SublimeText3 with sublime_plugin.EventListener class. I want to replace `key1` to `replace1` by on_query_completions method. But I could not that. How to know bind class method to on_query_completions method? Or, How to alternative way?

```
class MyPlugin(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        """ success, but this is not to hoped """
        return [
            ['key1', 'replace1'],
            ['key2', 'replace2'],
        ]

    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        """ not working, but this is I hoped """
        return [
            ['key1', self.replace1],
            ['key2', self.replace2],
        ]

    def replace1(self):
        return 'replace2'

    def replace2(self):
        return 'replace2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work as written because `self.replace1` and `self.replace2` are not strings, they're functions (methods) and the return value from `on_query_completions` needs strings.

If your intention is to get the result of the methods and use those as the replacement text, you should call them and not just reference them:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class MyPlugin(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        """ not working, but this is I hoped """
        return [
            ['key1', self.replace1()],
            ['key2', self.replace2()],
        ]

    def replace1(self):
        return 'replace1'

    def replace2(self):
        return 'replace2'
```

Comment: `def replace1(self):` should return `'replace1'`, assuming the OP also meant that which seems likely.

Comment: Originally I left that alone in favor of just showing why the code wasn't working, but I agree that it's better to have an example working as intended.